# passing data servlet to jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

While I am trying to pass data to jsp from servlet, data is passing successfully but, it appears like alert, actually I want to display it in new jsp page.

here is my servlet and the jsp file that I want to display it,

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Servlet called!!");
    String feature=request.getParameter("id");  
    PrintWriter out = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt=null;
    ResultSet rs;
    try{
        conn = JBDC.ConnectionFactory.getConnection();

        // Execute SQL query
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT * FROM customers.add_voice where Feature='" +feature+  "'";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


        // Extract data from DB
        if(!rs.next()){
            //Do nothing
        }else{
            do{
                String price = rs.getString("Price");
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                request.setAttribute("feature", feature);
                request.setAttribute("price", price);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/SelectedFeature.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }while(rs.next());
        }

        // Clean-up
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
        //Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        //Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try{
            if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close();
        }catch(SQLException se2){
        }
        try{
            if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

//in jsp I am fetching it

```
<%=(String)request.getAttribute("feature")%>
<%=(String)request.getAttribute("price")%>
```

[what I mean by alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS2v1.jpg)

//my jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<META http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<script src="javascript/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="WebContent/javascript/basic.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/basic.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%=(String)request.getAttribute("feature")%>
    <%=(String)request.getAttribute("price")%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you mean by it appears like alert. You are passing to a page using forward method and using getAttribute() method getting parameters. What you need exactly?

Comment: @Santhucool I add a picture pls check it

Comment: did not see any pic yet

Comment: just click "what I mean by alert" at the end of the post :) @Santhucool

Comment: provide your jsp page code. If you simple add scriptlets in your jsp page alert won't come. It will simply print like normal html. I mean SelectedFeature.jsp code

Comment: I add my jsp @Santhucool

Comment: try like this  `RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/SelectedFeature.jsp");  
        rd.forward(request, response);`   instead of `request.getRequestDispatcher("/SelectedFeature.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Comment: I tried it, nothing changed :( @Santhucool

Comment: You are simply putting it inside body tag so alert should not come.

Comment: comment scripts and try again for testing `<!-- <script src="javascript/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="WebContent/javascript/basic.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/basic.js"></script>-->`

Comment: I tried it too, nothing changed, my servlet getting a string from ajax and its using that string in database search, what I want as a result is, simply new jsp page with the result. @Santhucool

Comment: So you are simply getting ajax from this servlet response? Then why you using forward method? simply call that servlet from ajax. In case of ajax you do not require 
`<script src="javascript/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="WebContent/javascript/basic.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/basic.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>` simply remove those. If your jsp is ajax page

Comment: let me explain it more clear, my index.jsp has three clickable feature in it, and my ajax method is taking the clicked feature name and, sending it to the servlet, servlet doing a search query with this feature and return with its price. All process is seems well, it return with correct price but it is displaying it in alert dialog. @Santhucool

Comment: alert coming because you are putting ajax response in ajax.

Comment: my ajax  function is in basic.js, not the same with SelectedFeature.jsp , or maybe I couldnt understand what you are trying to explain. @Santhucool

Answer (score 0):

It's not an alert, your JSP file is telling the browser that the output content is a stylesheet.

`<META http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">`

Change the `"text/css"` to `"text/html"` since what you appear to be sending back is HTML.

Though in your comments you say this is an AJAX request, so what you want to send back probably isn't HTML and you need to rethink using a JSP for the response, since AJAX requests don't typically use HTML for data transfer.

Comment: can you check this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075724/passing-data-to-jsp-from-servlet), I asked it more clearly in there. also I added my js file and the part "alert(data)" causing that problem. But, I don't know how can I open new page through this function. I've already try window.location but, it didn't work. @markolsson